# Can't override homepage trailing slash

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-routing

My site have no "homepage" that use the base url (mydomain.com)
The default routing include the `_locale` parameter, and thus, fail to match one part of the route depending on how I set it.

<kbd>**Config A**</kbd>

```
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}/
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
    requirements:
        _locale: '%locales%'
```

This first config will match the route homepage with the following URLs

> mydomain.com/en
>   mydomain.com/en/

But will fail to match

> mydomain.com
>   mydomain.com/

<kbd>**Config B**</kbd>

```
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
    requirements:
        _locale: '%locales%'
```

This second config will match the route homepage with the following URLs

> mydomain.com
>   mydomain.com/
>   mydomain.com/en

But will fail to match

> mydomain.com/en/

Any idea what I'm missing in my config to match the 4 possibles URL patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
homepage:
    path: /{_locale}{trailingSlash}
    defaults:
        _locale: '%locale%'
        trailingSlash: ''
    requirements:
        _locale: '%locales%'
        trailingSlash: /?
```